# Вывод данных из БД, при условии

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

хочу сделать вывод данных из БД, ТОЛЬКО при *условии*, что **переменная** на странице будет **соответствовать** названию **таблицы** из БД. но не получается реализовать

- *Таблица* в БД называется **table1**.
- *переменная* на странице **$peremen = "table1"**.

Далее **неполуается** реализовать проверку, а она должна выглядеть и звучать следующим образом:

============================

*ЕСЛИ переменная **$peremen** равна **Названию таблицы (table1)**, то производится следующее соединение с базой данных:*

```html
session_start();
$id = $_GET['id']; 
$t = $_GET['t']; 
require 'conect.php';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $t WHERE id='$id' ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
 
$text = "".nl2br($row['text'])."";
 $au = $row['name']; 
$ar = $row['type']; 
$tg = $row['tags'];
} 
else {
 echo "Ничего нового....";
}
```

*В противном случае ничего выводиться не должно.*

==========================================================

вот так должен выглядеть запрос с проверкой на переменную, но все мои попытки её реализовать - тщетны..

Comment: и как они выглядят, попытки эти ваши?

Comment: Тебе это не нужно.

Answer (score 0):

*но все мои попытки её реализовать - тщетны..*
Попрообуйте так:

```
if ($peremen == 'table1') {
    // переменная равна названию вашей таблицы table1, можете подключаться
    ...
}
else {
    // не равна, делаете что-то другое
}
```

Comment: 0xdb, извините за сарказм, я так больше не буду.

Comment: Прямо любопытно стало, почему минус ответу?